# scala returning a Future[Option[user]]

Tags: scala

So, I am totally new to Scala, coming from a Java background and have been given a huge scala code base to learn.  And, I am very lost and would appreciate any help.

I have the below function that I want to re-arrange.  Currently, the function calls two functions in a row and then returns the result.  The first function returns a boolean and the second function returns a User.  However, what actually should happen is that the second function should only be called if the first function returns true.  So, I need to rearrange it to check the return value of the first function before continuing.  Every time I rewrite it to do that, I either get a compile error or exception.  It is supposed to return a Future[Option[User]] and the first function doesn't return a User.  I just want to return None if FunctionA fails, but because it expects Future[Option[X]]], it is unhappy.  So, below is the function:

```
private def profileForCredentials(userId: String, password: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[User]] =
  {
      val credentials: Throwable \/ Boolean = {
      try {
         FunctionA(userId, password).right[Throwable]
      }
      catch {
        case npe: NullPointerException =>
          npe.left[Boolean]
      }
    }

    //This function doesn't need to be called unless credentials=true
    FunctionB(id, userId).map {
        case maybeUser@Some(user) =>
          credentials match {
            case \/-(x) if x =>
              user.some
            case _ =>
              None
          }
        case None =>
          None
      }
}
```

Comment: Where is the ``Future``?

Comment: Try return `Future { None }` not `None`

Comment: @Jean Logeart FunctionB propably returns Future.

Comment: We need the return types of ``FunctionA`` and ``FunctionB`` to help you

Answer (score 3):

You guys just got carried away with the scalaz. 
I am going to bookmark this page to show people at work as an illustration why we should not be using all this fancy stuff.

Just do this:

```
    Try { 
       FunctionA(userId, password)
    }
    .toOption
    .collect { case(true) => 
      FunctionB(id, userId)
    }
    .getOrElse(Future.value(None))
```